# Tracking down a distributed tranaction error

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection, distributed-transactions

How can I track down the distributed trans error? Are there any ways to determine all connections are still open? I need to find the transaction that wasn't properly closed?

I'm getting an occasional distributed transaction error with the following code when I fill a table from an adapter. I suspect the error may not be in this code, but this is where the error tends to pop up, only on the second try, the first always works okay.

```
using (OracleConnection oraConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString)){
 using (OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand( "DB_SCHEMA." + rmd.storedprocName, oraConnection )){
    oraCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    if ( rmd.parameters != null ){
        for ( int i = 0; i <= rmd.parameters.GetUpperBound( 0 ); i++ )
        {
            OracleParameter oraParameter = new OracleParameter();
            oraParameter.ParameterName = rmd.parameterNames[ i ];
            oraParameter.OracleDbType = rmd.parameterTypes[ i ];
            oraParameter.Size = 15;

            string dataType = oraParameter.OracleDbType.ToString().ToUpper();

            switch ( dataType )
            {
                case "VARCHAR2":
                    oraParameter.Value = rmd.parameters[ i ].ToString();
                    break;
                case "CHAR":
                    oraParameter.Value = rmd.parameters[ i ].ToString();
                    break;
                case "NUMBER":
                    oraParameter.Value = Convert.ToDouble( rmd.parameters[ i ] );
                    break;
                case "DATE":
                    oraParameter.Value = Convert.ToDateTime( rmd.parameters[ i ] );
                    break;
                default:
                    oraParameter.Value = rmd.parameters[ i ].ToString();
                    break;
            }

            oraCommand.Parameters.Add( oraParameter );

        }
    }

  oraCommand.Parameters.Add( "RS", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
   OracleDataAdapter oraDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter( oraCommand );
   oraDataAdapter.Fill( dataTable );  //< -- error is thrown here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where the problem is originating from, but I suspect it is due to the use of an `OracleDataAdapter` while you already have an `OracleCommand` and `OracleConnection` object.

I think using an `OracleDataReader` to fill your table and calling the `Open()` and `Close()` methods off your connection would be cleaner.

After you assign all your parameters to `oraCommand` try this instead of your `DataAdapter`:

```
    oraConnection.Open();
    OracleDataReader dr = oraCommand.ExecuteReader();
    dataTable.Load(dr);
    oraConnection.Close();
```

Again, I don't think this will necessarily "fix" your transaction error, but it should ensure that you only have one open connection at the time of execution for the stored procedure, thus making the connection more manageable.

Here is an example of using a `TransactionScope` object for your data access:

```
    try
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions(){IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted}))
        try
        {
            CallYourDataAccessMethodsHere();
            scope.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle or log the error during the transaction
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //This will catch a TransactionAbortedException and hopefully help track down the problem
    }
```

Comment: in msdn, it says 'More than one OracleDataReader can be open at any given time.' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4kxd8h.aspx) so I tried using it open mulitple connections, but I still got the error.

Comment: On second thought, you may want to consider using a `TransactionScope` for all your data access methods ensuring that all access and reading is done during the scope of all transactions to the database.  The other possibility is that there is something going wrong in the Stored Procedure itself, maybe try doing some error handling there instead of a rollback?  Or post the stored procedure and we can take a look.

Comment: I added some code to my original answer to demonstrate the use of a `TransactionScope` object.